# When searching on Careers "Reading List", there is no feedback when no results are found

Tags: bug

Steps to reproduce:

- Go to the profile page on Careers
- Under "Reading", Click on "add a book you've read". Type something that doesn't yield
  results into the text box, e.g. "The Coding Dojo Handbook"
- Click the "search" button.

What I expected:

To get some feedback that no results were found.

What I got:

It looks like nothing happens when you click the button, giving the impression that something is broken rather than no results being found.